# Website categories

Tags: html, wordpress, filter

I have recently finished creating a website without using Wordpress, yet web filters like Fortinet/Fortiguard or Qustodio declare that my site's category is "unrated", therefore not letting the site to be visible.

Is there a possibility or method to assign a category to the site through HTML coding, or is it obligatory to use Wordpress so the site can be recognized as not-unrated category-wise?

Apologies for the redundances, and thanks beforehand.

Comment: I can't help but cringe at `cathegory`.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a possibility or method to assign a cathegory to the site through HTML coding

No.

> or is it obligatory to use Wordpress so the site can be recognized as not-unrated cathegory-wise?

That won't work either.

---

The category is determined by the filter's own rules, not by the website.

Comment: Thought so, but still had to ask. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Those sites determine your website's category by looking at the content and the people who visit it. These actually take time. Be patient.

Comment: Will it help if I add some tags within the site? I am adverse to using Wordpress for various reasons, so I prefer to do them on my own. Thanks.